# React Table: _pivotVal converts object to string "[Object Object]"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I am using the pivot feature of react table.
I have passed my custom renderer to the cell, which accepts an object as value.
When i'm trying using Pivot, the corresponding _pivotVal is turning out to be a string "[Object Object]" rather than an object.
Any help is much appreciated.